# Confusion on google api query limit for chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-api

I'm super new to making chrome extensions, but I really wanted to make one that let me highlight text and just do a simple same-page google image search of that text by clicking the extension button and opening a popup of the returned images from the query. 
So I made it and tested it using the deprecated google image search api. I want to put it live but I'm genuinely confused about the query limits. I have no intention to make money off of it in any way, considering the primary content of the extension is just a google image search. I just always hated having to open a new tab to search for images of a word I see on a website when surfing the web.

Also is it even possible to upload it to the store when it's using the deprecated google image search api that still works for some reason even without a key. Or would I need to update it to using the custom search api, which has only free 100 queries per day. And can someone explain that? 
If it's an extension, and a end user clicks on the extension button and it queries google custom search api, I'd only have 99 queries left for that day? So only about 2-5 people could actively use it during the day before the limit is reached? I spent hours reading stuff but I still don't quite understand.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the Image Search API. It was deprecated in May, 2011 with bests effort to keep it running for three years. It's now well past that best effort timeframe so I can disappear without notice leaving your extension broken.

The Custom Search JSON/Atom API free tier is 100 searches per day for your entire application. That that could be 100 people making one query each or 1 person making 100 queries.